# xslt arborescence works only partially

Tags: xslt

I use xslt to extract information form a xml file.

the xml file is :

```
<object>
    <identifier>identifier</identifier>
    <link>UD</link>
    <title>Current Title</tite>
    <impact>
        <product>The product</product>
        <evolution id="Evo 1">
            <descr>Current description</descr>
        </evolution>
    </impact>
</object>
```

my xlst file is :

```
<xsl:for-each  select="//object">

<tr>                        
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="identifier"/>
</td>
<td>
      <xsl:value-of select="link"/>
</td>
<td>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</td>
<td>
      <xsl:value-of select="impact[1]/product"/>
</td>
<td>
      <xsl:value-of select="impact[1]/product/evolution[1]/@id"/>
    </td>
<td>
      <xsl:value-of select="impact[1]/product/evolution[1]/descr"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

However, I can't seem to get the last two xsl values, I must have made a mistake (the first 4 columns are OK). Could you explain me why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evolution is a sibling, not a child of `product` - it is a direct child of impact.

```
  <xsl:value-of select="impact[1]/evolution[1]/@id"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="impact[1]/evolution[1]/descr"/>
```